# Who is owner of incrond file products?

Tags: cron

Consider this command: `sudo incrontab ~/incron-config` where `~/incron-config` contains:

```
/home/zetah/Documents/incoming IN_CREATE,IN_MOVED_TO /home/zetah/scripts/do_something.sh $@/$#
```

and `do_something.sh` consists of:

```
#! /bin/bash

python /home/zetah/scripts/py_something.py "$1"
```

Python script accesses some online services and produces 3 new files. They are owned by `root`.
Why is that and how can I change this behavior. I want to be the owner of those product files

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running `incrontab` under `sudo`, you are updating root's configuration.  Therefore, your script is also run as root.

If you run `incrontab` without `sudo`, your script should be run under your own user account.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that running with `sudo` is the only way there is